# Amazon EC2 Image with VNC enabled?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I want to fire up an linux EC2 instance that has VNC installed by default.  Something like Ubuntu, where I can fire up, and VNC right in to configure.

I've observed all of the AMI's that are available, and the closest thing I can come to, is:

```
SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp3 (HVM) - ami-xxxxxxx

SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 3 (HVM), EBS-backed. Nvidia driver installs automatically during startup for GPU instances.
```

I assume that this has graphic capabilities, but you know what they say about assumptions.

Does anybody know of an image that has this?  I just want to fire up an instance that I can get right into, not through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The images you are looking at are designed for the largest (HVM) instances. The second one is intended for GPU instances. Probably not what you are looking for if you just want VNC.

Often most AMI's don't have any desktop systems installed as they are generally intended to be run as headless servers. But you should be able to take a base Ubuntu instance, install a desktop system and vnc and then repackage it as an AMI for your own use.

Comment: that was my original thought.. i wasn't sure if there was a vanilla plug and play instance for what i wanted.. i may just have to do that.

Comment: @sircapsalot There may be a third party AMI that provides that. Use those ones at your own risk.